# Notification code for API levels lower than 26

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to target my Android application from API level 23 to the latest API level. However starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel which wasn't the case previously. Right now I am checking the condition  `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` to make the notification with the NotificationChannel if API level is greater than 26, so my question is that will the import statement for the NotificationChannel `import android.app.NotificationChannel;`
 cause an issue in the API versions lower than 26. Should I maintain different activities for the different APIs?

Comment: no issue with the import statement carry on, bonus just for ref https://github.com/Hemen07/Nimbus-Todo-pad-Reminder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/redfox/nimbustodo/util/alarm_util/UtilNotification.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the import statement for the NotificationChannel import android.app.NotificationChannel; cause an issue in the API versions lower than 26.

No.

Trying to *use* `NotificationChannel` on older devices would be a problem, but that is what the `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)` is for. Simply having the import will not be an issue.